# React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "handleNameChange" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that is called every time the NAME state is changed. And I would like to send this changed value to the parent component, but it is pointing out this error:

```
React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "handleNameChange" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function       react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

code:

```
export default function config({ me, setMePut }) {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState(me.name);

  function handleNameChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);

    useEffect(() => {
      setMePut({
        name: name,
      });
    }, [setMePut]);
  }

  return (
    <BoxFormGrid>
      <Label>Nome</Label>
      <Input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
    </BoxFormGrid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Not sure what it is you want to do. You have a local state called name and a prop called me.name and you want to set them both when you change an input? Why have a local copy of me.name if they're both the same?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)

> you can only call Hooks at the top level. Don’t call Hooks inside
>   loops, conditions, or nested functions.

Your useEffect hook is inside a function. If keeping useEffect at top level not meeting your requirements then you can create a custom hook.

You can change your component like this to make it work.

```
export default function config({ me, setMePut }) { //would suggest you to start react ccomponent with uppercaseletter//
  const [name, setName] = React.useState(me.name);

 useEffect(() => {
      setMePut({
        name: name,
      });
    }, [name, setMePut]);

  function handleNameChange(event) {
    setName(event.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <BoxFormGrid>
      <Label>Nome</Label>
      <Input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
    </BoxFormGrid>
  );
}
```

As HMR pointed out. There's no need to create a state for what you are doing. You can simply refactor your component to -

```
export default function config({ me, setMePut }) {

  function handleNameChange(event) {
    setMePut(prevState => ({ ...prevState, name: event.target.value }));
  }

  return (
    <BoxFormGrid>
      <Label>Nome</Label>
      <Input type="text" value={me.name} onChange={handleNameChange} />
    </BoxFormGrid>
  );
}
```

Comment: It solves the error but the code is still bad for copying me.name for no reason.

Comment: @HMR I agree. You can use me and setMePut directly. There's no need for creating a new state for it.

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` can only be used in the top level of a functional component, hence it is throwing the error.

For the use case that you have mentioned, you can move the `useEffect` outside and specify the required changing prop as dependency.

```
export default function config({ me, setMePut }) {

  useEffect(() => {
    setMePut({
      name: name,
    });
  }, [name, setMePut]);
}
```

Whenever `name` changes, this function would be run and you can achieve the result.